# Laravel Session data not written/update/availabe in View when using AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel-4

When I add things to the Session with `Session::put()` in my controller action, then that data is not available in my view, with `Session::get()` when doing AJAX request.

The same problem goes for the Former package, which I use for nice form building. It relies on passing some info via the Session, which is used to mark fields as valid/invalid. This functionality is also not working when using AJAX.

I set a view like always, in my View:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('account.login')
```

For AJAX requests, I do NOT render the normal way with layout, but instead get the specific "content" section of the template and return it:

```
$this->layout->content->renderSections()['content']
```

- When I do a "normal" request, then Session data works fine.
- When I do an AJAX request, then **Session data set in the controller DURING the AJAX call** is ignored. Any Session data set BEFORE the AJAX call is available.

**I'm wondering if Laravel has some issue with Session under AJAX calls, or with the the "renderSection()" method above?**

I have checked all the obvious problems:

- AJAX request uses the same session ID as non-AJAX request.
- GET/POST verbs are used correctly etc.

**Replicate:**

- In CONTROLLER action: `Session:put('foo','bar');`
- In VIEW file (in the content part): `Session:put('foo2','bar2');`
- In VIEW file (in the content part): `var_dump(Session::get('foo','bar'));` **// Returns 'bar' in non-AJAX calls, but returns nothing for AJAX calls (!!!)**
- In VIEW file (in the content part): `var_dump(Session::get('foo2'));` // Returns 'bar2' in both AJAX and non-AJAX calls as expected.

It seems like the Session values set in the controller action ARE LOST when it renders the view. Therefore my question if this is 1) an AJAX vs. SESSION issue in Laravel, or 2) an Session vs. renderElement() problem that I am not aware of?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem - a form submit with ajax to a cart function. THe session is created within the function but as soon as I move to another method eg get cart the session does not exist or created! Have you been able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just found a potential solution:

I found a similar problem relating to laravel 3. For the session to persist in an ajax call you need to return the response correctly.

```
return json_encode($response);
```

This is causing the problem. It's not it appears a valid response to enable the session to persist. Change it to:

```
return Response::json($response);
```

This enables the session to persist!

For some reason a normal form submit or call to the method allows the first one but ajax does not.

I've seen references elsewhere about echo statements in the method affecting the session - the return I suppose must behaving similar to an echo

This is the post that triggered the solution:
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1304